# what type of an array for the p[f].firstname, p[f].lastname, etc.and how what does it means return "no statues"? I still have two another questions

Tags: arrays, function, multidimensional-array, return, return-type

Hi I have been doing a project for tic tac toe with some references and examples but there are some things that I cannot understand in this one coding I found in chegg. Our lecturer gave us a project and find our own references (which means we need to learn by ourselves for some coding terms we have never seen). Here I show the coding and the questions I have:

1. what type of an array for the p[f].firstname, p[f].lastname, etc. I need an explanation of why the array is needed for this project
2. I am still confused about the return type for the return "no statues" in the function 'string status(char board[9]) '
3. In the int main() function, I do not understand why the move must be minus one in the 'board[move-1]=P[f].mark'
4. why [(f+1)%2].mark is needed ?

It would be great if anyone can also give me references/pages from the 'A first book for C++ (Introduction to Programming), 4th edition'

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
/**Player class**/
class Player 
{
    public:  
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    char mark;
    int wins,losses,draws;
    Player()
    {
        wins=losses=draws=0;
    }
};
/**function to print board**/
void print_board(char board[])
{
    cout<<' '<<"___"<<' '<<"___"<<' '<<"___"<<' '<<'\n';
    cout<<"| "<<board[0]<<" | "<<board[1]<<" | "<<board[2]<<" | "<<'\n';
    
    cout<<'|'<<"___"<<'|'<<"___"<<'|'<<"___"<<'|'<<'\n';
    cout<<"| "<<board[3]<<" | "<<board[4]<<" | "<<board[5]<<" | "<<'\n';
   
    cout<<'|'<<"___"<<'|'<<"___"<<'|'<<"___"<<'|'<<'\n';
    cout<<"| "<<board[6]<<" | "<<board[7]<<" | "<<board[8]<<" | "<<'\n';
   
    cout<<'|'<<"___"<<'|'<<"___"<<'|'<<"___"<<'|'<<'\n';
}
/**function to check status of board**/
string status(char board[9])
{
    bool draw = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9 ; i++)
    draw &= (board[i]!=' ');
    if(draw) return "draw";

    /**horizontal**/
    for(int i =0 ; i <9 ;i=i+3)
    if(board[i]!=' '&&board[i]==board[i+1]&&board[i+1]==board[i+2])
        {
            board[i]=toupper(board[i]);
            board[i+1]=toupper(board[i+1]);
            board[i+2]=toupper(board[i+2]);
            return "win";
        }

    /**vertical**/
    for(int i =0 ; i <3; i++)
    if(board[i]!=' '&&board[i]==board[i+3]&&board[i+3]==board[i+6])
        {
            board[i]=toupper(board[i]);
            board[i+3]=toupper(board[i+3]);
            board[i+6]=toupper(board[i+6]);
            return "win";
        }

    /**diagonal 1**/
    if(board[0]!=' '&&board[0]==board[4]&&board[4]==board[8])
        {
            board[0]=toupper(board[0]);
            board[4]=toupper(board[4]);
            board[8]=toupper(board[8]);
            return "win";
        }

    /**diagonal 2**/
    if(board[2]!=' '&&board[2]==board[4]&&board[4]==board[6])
        {
            board[2]=toupper(board[2]);
            board[4]=toupper(board[4]);
            board[6]=toupper(board[6]);
            return "win";
        }

return "no_status"; 
}

/**function to get valid input for move**/
int valid(char board[])
{
    int turn; cin>>turn;
    if(turn<1 || turn >9)
        {
            cout<<"Invalid move!!";
            cout<<"Re-enter your move: ";
            return valid(board);
        }

    if(board[turn-1]!=' ')
        {
            cout<<"Move already Played!!";
            cout<<"Re-enter your move: ";
            return valid(board);
        }

    return turn;

}

int main()
{

    /**simulating game**/
    Player P[2];
    cout<<"Enter Player-0's name: ";
    cin>>P[0].firstname>>P[0].lastname; 
    cout<<"Enter Player-1's name: ";
    cin>>P[1].firstname>>P[1].lastname;

    int f=1;
    cout<<"Who plays first? [Press 0 or 1]: ";
    cin>>f;

    P[f].mark='x';
    P[(f+1)%2].mark='o';
    char board[9]={' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};
    bool quit=false;

    while(!quit)
        {
            system("cls");
            print_board(board);
            cout<<P[f].firstname<<"'s move. Please choose 1-9: ";
            int move = valid(board);
            board[move-1]=P[f].mark;
            string sts=status(board);
            if(sts=="win"||sts=="draw")
            {
                if(sts=="win")
                {
                    system("cls");
                    print_board(board);
                    P[f].wins++;
                    P[(f+1)%2].losses++;
                }
                else
                {
                    P[f].draws++;
                    P[(f+1)%2].draws++;
                }

                cout<<setw(20)<<" ____________________"<<"_ ______ ________ _______ \n";
                cout<<"|"<<setw(20)<<" PLAYER-NAME "<<" | WINS | LOSSES | DRAWS |\n";
                cout<<setw(20)<<"|____________________"<<"_|______|________|_______|\n";

                for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
                cout<<"|"<<setw(20)<<(P[i].firstname+" "+P[i].lastname)<<" | "<<setw(4)<<P[i].wins<<" | "<<setw(6)<<P[i].losses<<" | "<<setw(5)<<P[i].draws<<" |\n";
                cout<<setw(20)<<"|____________________"<<"_|______|________|_______|\n";

                cout<<"\nQuit? [if yes, press y / if no, press any key] : ";
                char c;
                cin>>c;

                if(c=='y')
                break;
                else
                    {
                        for(int i=0; i < 9 ; i++) //initialize all as {} again (before was x or o)
                        board[i]=' ';
                    }
            }
            f=(f+1)%2;

        }


}
```